# Syntax error using Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm developing an app and there will be user accounts. So my first step is for the user to enter their full name but every time I get this error:

[Error]: invalid field name: Full Name (Code: 105, Version: 1.7.1)

Here is my code:

//Gets text from TextField when TextField finished editing

```
-(IBAction)getFullName:(id)sender {

fullN = self.fullName.text;

}
```

//Main Method

```
- (IBAction)signUp:(id)sender{

    PFObject *users = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Users"];
    users[@"Full Name"] = fullN;

   [users saveInBackground];  
}
```

Please help!

Comment: I don't use parse.com, but do they allow spaces in their names?

Comment: @Droppy - I use it, and you're exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

Parse doesn't allow spaces in their names.

Thanks to Droppy[1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3588973/droppy/)